# How to use Python asyncio on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function triggered by HTTP request does following two tasks:

```
def task1():
  do sth
  return info

def task2(info):
  do sth
  
def main(request)
  info=task1()
  if (info):
    task2(info)
  return info
```

I would like the function returns without waiting the task2 completes. So I did following changes:

```
import asyncio

def task1():
  do sth
  return info

async def task2(info):
  do sth

async def bar(info):
  return await task2(info)
  
def main(request)
  info=task1()
  if (info):
    asyncio.run(bar(info))
  return info
```

Not sure if I did is correct? But I didn't notice the function gets any faster. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: If this is the only code your testing, I don't think you would notice much of a difference (unless there's just a crazy amount of processing happening in the calls). Also, run() can't be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread. Might be a bottle neck in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutines are designed to leverage CPU concurrent processing. Typically, when you can call a URL and wait the response, there is time (some milliseconds). Instead of doing nothing you can use the unused CPU power to process another coroutine. It's more efficient and, ideally, the max processing time is equals to the slowest coroutine (or API call in my example).

in your example, there is no wait, no time where the CPU do nothing (a sleep, a URL call) and thus you can't leverage the concurrency process. In addition, you need to have 2 or more coroutine to see the benefit of concurrent execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually both my tasks include a couple rest calls. I want to see if the cloud function could return the caller the result from the task1 without waiting the task2 completes since task2 takes about 3 seconds to complete.